# How to control c++ class object in python?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I want controlling c++ class object in python.

I'm expected example.

1. Objected class in c++ and send object to python.

   ```
   class Animal animal();
   PyObject *py_func = PyObject_GetAttrString(mymodule, "ControlAnimal");
   PyObject_CallFunction(func, "class Animal", animal);
   ```
2. Control object in python.

   ```
   def ControlAnimal(animal) // Get animal object is created object from c++.
       pass
   ```
3. if object is controlled in python, animal in c++ is also applied because animal is c++ object's reference in python.

I already try SWIG and succeeded binding Animal class to python.

```
python.
>> import animal
>> a = animal.Animal()
```

But it only control created class object  in python.

Sorry bad english.

Comment: You might want to write an [extension module](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html#)

Comment: Thank reply. But c++ extension module can only use in python. I want that created object in c++ is controlled in python function.

Comment: The extension is for providing a defined interface for python to access some *arbitrary* C++ API. Appropriately defined C++ types can be used from within Python seamlessly. If you want to control already existing C++ types (which you cannot or don't want to modify), you can create wrapper objects around that provide the python interface to the wrapped type.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using static global variable.

declare static global variable shared python variable in header file.

```
static Animal* g_animal;
```

Write function to set and get g_animal.

```
Animal* SetCppInstance(PyObject* capsule);
Animal* GetCppInstance();
```

You can set created animal object pointer in c++ to use in python.
To set g_aniaml in python, use PyObject_CallFunction().

```
Animal aniaml;
PyObject *py_module_animal = PyImport_ImportModule("animal");
PyObject *py_module_animal_setcppinstance = PyObject_GetAttrString(py_module_animal, "SetCppInstance");
PyObject_CallFunction(py_module_animal_setcppinstance, "O", py_capsule_animal);
```

And you must get your python module. To get python animal module, I use swig.

Then, you should write control.py to control animal.

```
import animal
obj = animal.GetCppInstance()
...
```

Sure, You should Call control.py manually in c++.

```
PyImport_ImportModule("control");
```

Now, if you control obj in control.py, animal in c++ change also.

Comment: I updated this example source in [my github repo](https://github.com/Gakgu/Python-Plugin-In-Cpp-Example).